# What is the opencv C++ equivalent funciton for np.ma.masked_where

Tags: python, c++, mask, tensor

I was trying to threshold and create mask for my tensor as follow

```
prediction = prediction>0.5   ---  where prediciton is a 2D tensor normalized to [0,1], I am thresholiding the value as 0.5 

prediction = np.ma.masked_where(prediction == 0, prediction) -- this turns the entries of prediction into boolean values for subsequent processing 



predicted_mask = ((np.array(prediction))*255.0).astype(np.uint8) --finally here , change /generate image as a black and white
```

This was in python and it worked fine , I am looking to turn this into c++ / opencv ..Any help is apprecaited

Answer (score 1):

Masked_where is a numpy function, not an opencv function.
Unlike python where looping is relatively slow, for c++ you would often just write a function to loop through the array and apply the conditions you want directly.

However, if you do want to use masks, this answer may be useful [OpenCV cv::Mat set if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573311/opencv-cvmat-set-if)